# Android - Use 1 MainActivity to show a fragment then switch to a tabbed view pager and back again

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Firstly hello I'm new here!

I have an Android application which starts with a single activity containing a fragment. This fragment has a list view which is populated with some basic data from am SQLite database.

I would like once a list item is clicked to be able to open a viewpager and have 2 tabbed fragments display detailed informaton about the item clicked.

One of the 2 tabbed fragments will be able to update information related to the item in the data base like ticking off a shopping list.

I understand I can just create a 2nd activity which contains the 2 fragments in tabbed view and then read write data back to database and once finished refresh my original list view fragment.

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this without creating a 2nd activity and cut out the need to keep reading and writing to database from a 2nd activity?
I know callbacks implemented within a fragment can be used to udate data like this from the original activity but I can't work out how to swap out my single fragment to a 2 fragment tabbed view.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey all, I guess this may be a bit of a mission I've searched and searched but cannot find the answer to do this so I've decided to make my database access through a single instance and use a content provider for my second activity. I realise this doesn't solve my problem but will help streamline a bit by only having a single instance of the database handler active. Hopefully saves on a bit of memory unless someone can tell me otherwise? Thank you all anyway.